# How to raise PropertyChanged event for child properties?

Tags: c#, bindingsource

What i want to do is bind controls to an object, i have as a taxonomy. The problem im running into is when i do something like

```
private Taxonomy _currentTaxonomy = new Taxonomy() { TaxonomyID=0 };

public Taxonomy CurrentTaxonomy{
    get;
    set{
          _currentTaxonomy = value
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Taxonomy");
    }
}
```

This way when the taxonomy gets set it does a notification. But the problem is that I have controls that are bound to the values inside that taxonomy, that do not get notified when the taxonomy is set. So if I load a new taxonomy, no notifications are made.

For example using the Entity Framework if i try setting taxonomy like so:

```
CurrentTaxonomy = context.Taxonomies.Find(2);
```

The notify event, which looks like so:

```
public int TaxonomyID { 
    get { return _TaxonomyID; } 
    set { _TaxonomyID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("TaxonomyID"); } 
}
```

Does not get fired.

By request, the textbox binds like so:

```
tbTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", _currentTaxonomy, "Title", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: Did you try raising PropertyChanged event on individual properties inside Taxonomy class e.g. TaxonomyID ?

Comment: I do, but they dont get called on on `CurrentTaxonomy= Context.Taxonomies.Find(2);` for example;

Comment: What is the code in the setter? Also, why would you expect them to fire on Find? It should fire when you are set the value to something right? e.g. CurrentTaxonomy.TaxonomyID = 3

Comment: I dont necissarily expect them to get fired, but i need them to be. if i have a taxonomyID textbox, and i set currentTaxonomy to a new taxonomy, with a new ID, i need that textbox to reflect the new taxonomy. I could reset the bindings, but i feel there should be a better way.

Comment: This should work fine. How is the databinding done in textbox?

Comment: @PiyushParashar updated question to reflect comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should databind to the property name `TaxonomyID`. Assuming your `BindingSource.DataSource` is pointing to `CurrentTaxonomy` class.

```
tbTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", _currentTaxonomy, "TaxonomyID", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

See this post:

[C# DataBinding - automatically writing changed property to label or textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785234/c-sharp-databinding-automatically-writing-changed-property-to-label-or-textbox)